# + name + not working in Python 3.8.2 shell

Tags: python

Using Python 3.8.2 and when I type `+ name +` it does not show the `name`. If you don't understand here is my code:

```
name=input('Enter your name: ')
print("Hi + name + what can I do for you?")
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Please go through a [tour](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). You can't just put plusses in the middle of a string and expect it to do something magical.

Comment: print("Hi " + name + " what can I do for you?")

Answer (score 2):

```
name=input('Enter your name: ')
```

Because `name` is a variable, it must be handled separately from the strings you want to concatenate it with. This should solve your problem.

```
print("Hi " + name + " what can I do for you?")
```

Notice several things:

The spaces in the quotes after the word `Hi` and before the word `what`. The spaces are characters, just like any letter and should be included.

NOTE: There are several other approaches that could also be used to concatenate text OR to allow for variables to be evaluated within strings.

#### print() automatically separates arguments with spaces

This approach takes advantage of the fact that behind the scenes, print() separate all arguments with a space:

```
print("Hi", name, "what can I do for you?")
```

### f-strings

The f-strings approach, which only works in really modern versions of Python is also very useful:

```
print(f"Hi {name} what can I do for you?")
```

Within f-strings, you can put variables inside of curly braces `{` and `}` and Python will automagically evaluate the variable for you and place the referenced value in the string.

Comment: Last one is not working for me... Can you please where I am going wrong? TIA           
 name = "aditi"

#f is for format string filling values at the place
#of placeholders

print(f"Hi {name}")

Answer (score 0):

Don't put all 3 arguments in the same string.

```
print("Hi",name,"what can I do for you?")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are directly printing a string. If you want to access the `name` variable, you can do the following:

```py
print("Hi " + name + " what can I do for you?")
```

Also, you can use fstrings, which are pretty useful:

```py
print(f"Hi {name} what can I do for you?")
```